# TensorFlow on Apple M1

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, apple-m1, metal

I seem to be unable to find any instructions to allow me to use TensorFlow with my M1 Ultra. Surely this is basic? What is happening?

The best I have come across is this:

https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706

But the notebook test suggests that only 1 of the GPUs is being used.

Comment: I think your question is assuming something that you have not disclosed, like, what do you mean only one of the GPUs?

Comment: There's only one GPU in M1 Ultra.

Comment: @Spo1ler Hadn't realised that...will try again.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use your mac M1 GPu to train models using tensorflow I suggest you to check out tensorflow-metal. it is a pluggable device of tensorflow.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) you find the official Apple guide on how to install it